# Link and sync folder between Google Drive & Google Cloud Shell Editor

Tags: google-drive-api, synchronization, editor, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I would like to **link** & **sync** folders between my ***Google Drive*** and ***Google Cloud Shell Editor*** (**$HOME**), in order to be able to edit and keep the files up to date everywhere.

I don't know as it's possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a feature to sync folders between Google Drive and Google Cloud Shell Editor.

If there was, most probably it would be mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/editor-overview).

You can [create a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187188&template=0) for Google to consider this feature.